# My probability plot and log scales do not line up with my gridlines (using ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot in which the x-axis has a probability scale and the y-axis is log-10-scaled. I'll start with my data, which can be found as a text file here:
http://m.uploadedit.com/b018/1374626091664.txt

I want to plot two data series based on the factor "Site", as you can see from the data. Well, when I go to plot the data, I naturally use `scale_x_continuous` with the `trans='probit'` option to generate a probability plot scale. I also generated a vector of breaks to use for the probability axis, named `ybreaks`:

`ybreaks <- c(1,2,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,95,98,99,99.5,99.9)/100`

```
ggplot(Site1A, aes(x=Prob, y=Volume))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=factor(Site)))+
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(Site)))+
  scale_x_continuous(trans='probit', minor_breaks=ybreaks)+
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma, breaks=c(.001,.01,.1,1,10,100))+
  labs(x="Exceedance Probability", y="Volume (cubic feet)")+
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Location", breaks=c("X1Ain","X1Aout"), labels=c("In","Out"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='#FFFFFF', colour = 'gray'),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=18),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=12),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=24),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=24, vjust=.1),
    legend.text=theme_text(size=23),
    legend.title=theme_text(size=23),
    legend.title=element_text())
```

Plot of the code is shown below:
[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to get minor gridlines for the probability axis to line up with the actual breaks, but it seems shrunken to some unknown scale. Also, the scale for the log axis is off (the breaks I'm specifying aren't lining up with the axis intervals for a log10 scale). How do I correct this? Thanks for any input you might have.

Comment: Part of the reason may be due to the fact that the documentation states that the `minor_breaks` argument to continuous scales is only for date and datetime axes. If you just use `breaks` the placements seem more reasonable.

Comment: (Sidenote: You're mixing code from different versions of ggplot here, with `theme_text` and `element_text`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently minor_breaks does not transform by itself. It should work if you use transform yourself with `qnorm`:

```
scale_x_continuous(trans='probit', minor_breaks=qnorm(ybreaks))
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. After adding `minor_breaks=qnorm(ybreaks)` and `breaks=ybreaks`, I had the solution I wanted: minor probability gridlines and corresponding axis intervals labelled. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to do this similarly for the log-scale (y-axis)?

Comment: You can do the same with `log10` instead of `qnorm`